# how to scan for port on windows

Tags: windows, port

Simple questions: is there a way to scan a parallel port on windows XP.
A command from the cmd would be great.

in other words, is there a netstats for parallel ports?

thank you very much!

Comment: What do you mean by "scan", and is this programming related?

Comment: I just want to see the status of the port, to see if there is an other application trying to use this port.

Comment: Check this SO post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2386169/how-to-find-available-parallel-ports-and-their-i-o-addresses-using-delphi-and-wmi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to open the port exclusively via CreateFile - if it fails, you know somebody else is using it.

Comment: Hi Paul, thank you for your answer. Sorry for the huge delay I didn't know my question magrated to serverfault.com

Comment: I'll try this soon!